# JWT authenticatiopn for iOS app

Tags: ios, authentication, jwt, laravel-5

I'm making an iOS app where I use Laravel 5.2 to develop my rest API. For user authentication I'm using JWT. When a user login from my app I'll send back a JWT. The question is can I set the expiring time for a Token to 'never', if that is possible, it's a good idea? Or should I refresh the token every x minute? If I should refresh the token every x minute, how can I do that and when should i do that. I want the user to always be logged in when first time logged in, except when the user manually log out ofcourse. I was thinking that each time a user fetch some private data I refresh the token?

PS: I can't post a conversation on laracast forum. Whenever i want to click 'post conversation' there is an error icon next to my mousearrow.

Answer (score 0):

I would negotiate a secret key between your client and backend. The client then would use that key to sign any requests to the server. The server can then reject that secret if you sign out, or if something else happens.

Just passing a short lived token to the client means it's really limited in what it can do. Passing the secret means the client can continue to sign requests long after the token expires. And even if an attacker gets the chance to listen to a token as it crosses the wire, it will be short lived, so of limited use.